# JsonSerializationException in Json Deserializing using Json.NET

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, json.net, deserialization

I have a Json like this :

```
[{"id":"54718","title":"Khaleda to visit China","corres":"Special Correspondent","details":"DHAKA: On a 7-day visit, opposition BNP Chairperson Khaleda Zia will leave Dhaka for China on October 14.","photo":"2012October\/SM\/Khaleda-new-sm20121003132805.jpg"}]
```

To parse this Json , so far I have done :

```
public class Attributes
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string ID{ get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string TITLE { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("corres")]
        public string CORRES { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("details")]
        public string  DETAIL { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("photo")]
        public string LINK { get; set; }
}

public class DataJsonAttributeContainer
{
    public List<Attributes> NewsList{ get; set; }
    //public Attributes attributes { get; set; }
}

public static T DeserializeFromJson<T>(string json)
{   //I'm getting the error here     
    T deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    return deserializedProduct;
}
```

& In my code :

```
 void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //parse data
            var container = DeserializeFromJson<DataJsonAttributeContainer>(e.Result);

            //load into list
            for (i = 0; i < container.NewsList.Count ; i++)
            {
                newData[i] = new data();
                newData[i].id = container.NewsList[i].ID;
                newData[i].title = container.NewsList[i].TITLE;
                newData[i].price = container.NewsList[i].CORRES;
                newData[i].image = container.NewsList[i].DETAIL;
                newData[i].link = container.NewsList[i].LINK;
            }
```

**The Problem is :** `container` is getting the json from web server which I can see at debugger , but it's shoeing an exception while deserializing . Can anybody help please ? 
The Exception I'm getting :

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'BanglaNewsPivot.MainPage+DataJsonAttributeContainer' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your json is an *array* (not *a single object containing array*). Calling your `DeserializeFromJson` as below

```
var attrs = DeserializeFromJson<List<Attributes>>(e.Result);
```

is enough.

--EDIT--

```
foreach (var attr in attrs)
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", attr.ID, attr.TITLE);
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate ? Where to put that code exactly ? I hope you won't mind since I am very new to c#.

Comment: @FahimAhmed just replace `var container = DeserializeFromJson<DataJsonAttributeContainer>(e.Result);` with the code above. Result(`attrs`) will be a list of `Attributes`. (No container object)

Comment: replaced & now getting the error at loading the values into a list . i.e 
 newData[i].corres = container.NewsList[i].CORRES; at `NewsList`

Comment: Basically my question is how to retieve data from it now ?

Comment: @FahimAhmed See the edit. OK you are new to c# but you don't show any effort to learn. Just use VS's debugger and see the content of `attrs`

Comment: Omg that took some time for me to get that the passed type has to be a list/array. Thank you very much!